# unable to set defaultValue in redux-form-material-ui TextField

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-form

I'm unable to set a default value for the textField component.
I tried using default value, but as long as I'm using the redux-form-material-ui it just doesn't work.

I really don't understand what am I doing wrong (seems pretty basic)...

exmaple (just changed their fieldArray example a little):

```
import React from 'react'
import { Field, FieldArray, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import validate from './validate'
import {TextField} from 'redux-form-material-ui'

const renderField = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    const { input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } } = props;
    console.log(input);
  return <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
// Will not show "someValue", it will just be blank
      <TextField defaultValue="someValue" {...input} type={type} placeholder={label}/>
      {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </div>
  </div>
}

const renderMembers = ({ fields, meta: { touched, error, submitFailed } }) => (
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push({})}>Add Member</button>
      {(touched || submitFailed) && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </li>
    {fields.map((member, index) =>
      <li key={index}>
        <button
          type="button"
          title="Remove Member"
          onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}/>
        <h4>Member #{index + 1}</h4>
        <Field
          name={`${member}.firstName`}
          type="text"
          component={renderField}
          label="First Name"/>
        <Field
          name={`${member}.lastName`}
          type="text"
          component={renderField}
          label="Last Name"/>
        <FieldArray name={`${member}.hobbies`} component={renderHobbies}/>
      </li>
    )}
  </ul>
)

const renderHobbies = ({ fields, meta: { error } }) => (
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push()}>Add Hobby</button>
    </li>
    {fields.map((hobby, index) =>
      <li key={index}>
        <button
          type="button"
          title="Remove Hobby"
          onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}/>
        <Field
          name={hobby}
          type="text"
          component={renderField}
          label={`Hobby #${index + 1}`}/>
      </li>
    )}
    {error && <li className="error">{error}</li>}
  </ul>
)

const FieldArraysForm = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field name="clubName" type="text" component={renderField} label="Club Name"/>
      <FieldArray name="members" component={renderMembers}/>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Submit</button>
        <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>Clear Values</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'fieldArrays',     // a unique identifier for this form
  validate
})(FieldArraysForm)
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should look at using initialValues - http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/initializeFromState/

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. Just read through the documentation again and saw this

No Default Values

Because of the strict "controlled component" nature of redux-form, some of the Material UI functionality related to defaulting of values has been disabled e.g. defaultValue, defaultDate, defaultTime, defaultToggled, defaultChecked, etc. If you need a field to be initialized to a certain state, you should use the initialValues API of redux-form.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably only one way to make form of editing.
It cannot be restored from initial redux Form values.

Input

```
export default function ({ input, label, meta: { touched, error }, ...custom }) {
    if ( input.value === '' && custom.cvalue ) { // hack for redux form with material components
        input.onChange(String(custom.cvalue));
    }
    return (
        <TextField
            {...input}
            {...custom}
            fullWidth={true}
            hintText={label}
            floatingLabelText={label}
            errorText={touched && error}
        />
    )
}
```

Select

```
export default function ({ input, label, meta: { touched, error }, onChange, children, ...custom }) {
    if ( input.value === '' && custom.cvalue ) { // hack for redux form with material components
        if ( is.function(onChange) ) {
            onChange(custom.cvalue);
        }
        input.onChange(custom.cvalue);
    }
    return (
        <SelectField
            {...input}
            {...custom}
            fullWidth={true}
            children={children}
            floatingLabelText={label}
            errorText={touched && error}
            onChange={(event, index, value) => {
                if ( is.function(onChange) ) { // and custom onChange for f....g ....
                    value = onChange(value);
                }
                input.onChange(value);
            }}/>
    )
}
```

> then in template
>       its can be way to make form of editing existing entity ....

```
<Field
    name="study"
    label="Studies"
    component={ FormSelect }
    cvalue={this.state.study.id}
    onChange={value => {
        this.setState({study: _.find(studies, {id: value})||{id: 0}});
         return value;
    }}>
    {studies.map( (study, key) => ( <MenuItem key={key} value={study.id} primaryText={study.officialTitle} /> ))}           
</Field>
```